# how to do onclick event Enable/Disable using single button

Tags: jquery

```
<button> Change Onclick</button>
<ul id="myorder"> 
    <li> <a href="#" onclick="popone();"> </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#" onclick="poptwo();"> </a> </li>    
</ul>
```

When I click on the button the first time the `onClick` must be disabled. After the second click on the button the `onClick` must enabled. How I do this? Can you help me? Can you give me jquery code?

Comment: simply track number of clicks using onclick handler of button and compare that if numberofclicks>1 and execute the popone() or poptwo() accordingly if you call server side code on that button then you can use storage mechanisms like in cookies etc.

Comment: Do you want to disable the link entirely, or just remove the event handler so it acts like a normal link?

Comment: disable / enable must toggle from my button

Comment: Is this homework by any chance? Because I answered virtually the same question two days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9051563/615754 (see my answer there for working demos in jsfiddle).

Comment: hi nnnnnn . ur answer is correct . but its not working in my project

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class for it or add the attribute disabled.

```
if($('#myorder a').attr('disabled') == 'disabled'){
// remove attribute disabled 
} else{
//disable them
}
```

or for the class

```
if($('#myorder a').hasClass('disabledClassName')){
//remove class
}else{
//add class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display hide whole  then you can use toggle of jquery as follow:

```
<button> Change Onclick</button>

<ul id="myorder"> 
<li> <a href="#" onclick="popone();"> </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#" onclick="poptwo();"> </a> </li>

</ul>

<script>

$("button").click(function () {
$("ul").toggle();
});
</script>
```

refer http://api.jquery.com/toggle/